# Run time complexity for Two for loops in One for loop

Tags: java, data-structures, runtime, big-o

I am writing a java method that finds the stability indexes for an array. My algorithm works fine but I am unsure of its run time complexity. I believe it is O(n) since the first loop is O(n) and the two inner loops are O(2n), but again I'm not sure.

```
int[] arr = {0, -3, 5, -4, -2, 3, 1, 0};

for(int num = 0; num < arr.length; num++){
    int sumLeft= 0;
    int sumRight = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<num; i++){
        sumLeft= sumLeft + arr[i];
    }
    for(int i = num + 1; i < arr.length;i++){
        sumRight= sumRight + arr[i];
    }
    if(sumLeft==sumRight){
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
3
7
```

Comment: It's O(n^2) - N elements examined N times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do two things:

- We can give you an answer, and that answer is `O(N^2)`.
- We can explain how to work it out for yourself.

The way to work it out is to count the operations.

When I say "count", I don't mean that literally.  What I actually mean is that you need to work out an *algebraic formula* for the number of times some *indicative* operation is performed.

So in your example, I would identify these two statement as the ones that are the most important:

```
      sumLeft= sumLeft + arr[i];

      sumRight= sumRight + arr[i];
```

(Why did I pick those statements?  Intuition / experience!  The *pedantic* way to do this is to count *all* operations.  But with experience, you can pick the important ones ... and the rest don't matter.)

So now for the formulae:

1. In one iteration of  the outer loop, the first statement is executed from `0 to num-1`; i.e. `num` times.
2. In one iteration of  the outer loop, the second statement is executed from `num+1 to array.length - 1`; i.e. `array.length - num - 1` times.
3. So, in one iteration of  the outer loop, the two statements are executed `num + array.length - num - 1` times which reduces to `array.length - 1` times.
4. But the outer loop runs `array.length` times.  So the two statements are executed `array.length x (array.length - 1)` times.

Finally, by the definition of Big Oh, `array.length x (array.length - 1)` is in the complexity class `O(N^2)` where `N` is the array size.

Answer (score 0):

it is O(n^2)

```
for(int num = 0; num < arr.length; num++){
    int sumLeft= 0;
    int sumRight = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<num; i++){// <------------- 1 ~ n
    //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF
        sumLeft= sumLeft + arr[i];
    }
    for(int i = num + 1; i < arr.length;i++){
        sumRight= sumRight + arr[i];
    }
    if(sumLeft==sumRight){
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```